# React Native on Android freezes after debugging for awhile

Tags: react-native

I've hooked up my brand new Kindle Fire 7 to my Mac and I've run `react-native run-android` successfully on it with Hot Reload and Remote JS Debugging enabled.

Everything seems to work fine for about 30 minutes or so, before the app completely freezes (no `console.log` statements show up, no UI updates, etc). When I shake my Fire, the debug menu does pop up (Reload, Stop Remote JS Debugging, Enable Live Reload, etc.), but tapping on any option is just as unresponsive.

If I run `adb devices` at this point on my Mac, I see that the Kindle Fire has disconnected. If then unplug the USB connection to my Fire, reconnect, and run `react-native run-android` again, everything works again for about 30 minutes and then it is unresponsive once more.

Has anyone else run into this issue? Thanks!

Note: I also highly doubt that my code is crashing the app... I'm just displaying the time on there with a single `setInterval` that grabs the current time. But just to be sure, I tried running with just a button that prints to the console on tap. That also stops working after running on the tablet for awhile.